# Javascript not executing in CMD

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with my homework assignment, I've coded the program to the best of my ability. However, I'm unable to run the code using the CMD nor NODE program on my desktop, can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Also, I have the program saved to my desktop instead of a folder, could this be the issue?

**Homework problem:  Write a program called pay.js, that calculates and displays an employee's total wages for the week. The regular hours for the work week are 40, and any hours worked over 40 are considered overtime. The employee earns $18.25 per hour for regular hours, and $27.78 per hour for overtime hours. The employee has worked 50 hours this week.  Display the result.**

**

- My Code

**

```
/*
This program will calculate an hourly employees total wages when working 40hrs, not to mention, if the the employee were to work ten hours of overtime.

input:
employee works 40hrs a week
employee hourly wage is $18.25
employee overtime wage is $27.78
employee worked 10hrs of overtime

output: 
standardhours + tenhoursofovertime

*/

var hoursperWeek = 40;
var hourlywage = 18.25;
var overtimewage = 27.78;
var overtimehoursWorked = 10;

var regularpay = hoursperWeek * hourlywage;
var overtimepay = overtimehoursWorked * overtimewage;
var regpayplusovertime = regularpay * overtimepay;

console.log(regpayplusovertime);
```

Comment: `I'm unable to run the code using the CMD nor NODE program on my desktop` - you can't run js in CMD ... how are you trying to run the code in node?

Comment: by using the path to my desktop, for example, C:Users/Username/Desktop/pay.js

Comment: well, if you have a node program, you need to run it in the CMD window using something like `node pay.js`

Comment: Okay, so I ran the CMD window using your suggestion and received this syntax error.                                                                                       Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 4.6.0 (x64) and npm.

C:\Users\Lawrence>node pay.js
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Lawrence\pay.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:974:3

Comment: You will have to redirect the CMD window to the folder the program is in. i.e. if your pay.js is in your Documents your would run 'cd C:\Users\USER_NAME\Documents' then run 'node pay.js' where USER_NAME for you is Lawrence. EDIT: also surely the line 'var regpayplusovertime = regularpay * overtimepay' should be 'var regpayplusovertime = regularpay + overtimepay'.

Comment: I tried your method and received  Windows Script Host pop-up window

Comment: you're double clicking the .js file if WSH pops up - or trying to "run" the .js file without using node

Comment: okay, so should this method work in the Node.js "C:\Users\Lawrence\Desktop\node pay.js? or "C:\Users\Lawrence\node pay.js

Answer (score 0):

```
var totalHours = 50;
var overtimeUpper = 40;

var regularWage = 18.25;
var overtimeWage = 27.78;

if(totalHours > overtimeUpper){
    var regularHours = overtimeUpper;
    var overtime = totalHours - overtimeUpper;
    var regularHoursWage = regularHours * regularWage;
    var overtimeHoursWage = overtime * overtimeWage;
    var totalWage = regularHoursWage + overtimeHoursWage;
    console.log(totalWage);
}
```